# Jest how to verify function is called on DOMContentLoaded event

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to write unit test for following code. I need to check initCarousel is called on document load
// carousel.js

```
document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    initCarousel();
});
```

Comment: Pass the event object to the listener, and check `event.type`. Though that function can be called only by `DOMContentLoaded` event, it's not accessible from anywhere else.

Comment: is it possible to mock DOMContentLoad and initCarousel method.with assert I need to check if mock function is invoked

Comment: Where does the `initCarousel` function come from? Please show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 init carousel is defined in same file.
function initCarousel() {
   // init carousel code
}
document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    initCarousel();
});